# Howto log embedded orientdb database with slf4j

Tags: logging, slf4j, orientdb

I start my application with an embedded database (plocal). OrientDB Version is 2.0 M2.

```
ODatabasePoolBase<ODatabaseDocumentTx> pool = new ODatabaseDocumentPool("plocal:" + database, getUsername(), getPassword());
```

In my application i use slf4j with "Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding" for logging.

I see any log message generated from my application in the log file.
Now i want to get the orientdb server log messages in the same log file for debugging purpose.

What i tried (unsuccessfully) so far:

- add jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar to the classpath and call 
  `SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();` 
  `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();` 
  at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Logging can be achieved by adding jul-to-slf4j to classpath:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Add this to your initialiation code

```
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.orientechnologies");
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

Now you can set indiviual log level in your log4j configuration:

```
    <Logger name="com.orientechnologies" level="INFO" />
```

Comment: I use two first lines of code: `SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
 SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();` 
and logs of orient-db is redirected to slf4j.

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB Server uses own LogFormatter. To use the same by your application call:

```
OLogManager.installCustomFormatter();
```

LogFormatter is installed automatically by Server. To disable it define the setting `orientdb.installCustomFormatter` to `false`. Example:

```
java ... -Dorientdb.installCustomFormatter=false=false ...
```

For more information look at the official documentation:
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Logging.html